# Wiki pages on Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki, canonical-questions

Wouldn't it be nice to have a page with just the answer (and maybe the questions) for some topics.

The fact that there has been an extensive discussion about a question isn't always relevant to someone who wants to just learn about the topic. For questions that are quite general. E.g. "What are generics?" a wiki page that has a complete answer without all the fluff of the comments and "wrong" answers would be nice. Links could then be put in these pages to refer to other wiki pages. Hey, I hear you saying "Why don't you just use Wikipedia?" well maybe Wikipedia should use SO. I mean SO is a lot easier to work with than Wikipedia so why not add more Wiki-style features to it. I just think the navigation around SO is not quite up to scratch. If I go to a question about generics there should be a link in the answer to a question about inheritance etc. much like Wikipedia allows for easy navigation around the "knowledge tree" if you will.

**Edit**

The problem with tags is that they give a whole bunch of specific questions instead of one with a general introduction/tutorial on the topic. For example I think there should be an equivalent of [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(computer_science)) on SO.

Comment: I'll argue that there's a real place for this sort of thing in answering RTFM type questions where the OP is showing confusion about the topic.  If you accumulate a collection of backgrounders, answers can refer to those documents.  The right grain of the topics is probably a bit too broad to shoehorn into tag wikis and doesn't really need wikipedia style citations if the actual essays are subjected to the same sort of peer review as other SO articles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jonathan, I completely agree. [I requested that SO implement similar functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/920/stackoverflow-tutorials-papers) some time back. There's simply too much knowledge on this site, and not enough organization. I'm with you on the fact that sometimes I don't want to learn from specific questions - I'd like to learn from a user-contributed documentation wiki. This is a proven method, and has seen great success in other areas. Taking into consideration the user-base of SO, their education, experience, and willingness to Edit, I can see this being a tremendous addition.

Answer (score 1):

One of the suggestions on uservoice is for [tag-specific home pages](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/138261-allow-a-per-tag-home-faq-page)... which (with an editable copy) would ideally provide some space to discuss a topic briefly, and link to the definitive frequent questions/answers for that topic...

Answer (score 0):

tags should work for this purpose. Click on the tag, then click on the "related tags" sidebar on the right. That will combine the tags.

The right sidebar will let you go up (to a single tag) or down (add another tag) fairly easily.